# Referencing variables in a structure / C++

Tags: c++, return, structure, pass-by-reference

Below, I provided a minimal example of code I created. I managed to get this code working, but I'm not sure if the practice being employed is sound. In essence, what I am trying to do is have the 'Parameter' class reference select elements in the 'States' class, so variables in States can be changed via Parameters.

Questions I have: is the approach taken OK? If not, is there a better way to achieve what I am aiming for?

Example code:

```
struct VAR_TYPE{
public:
    bool is_fixed;     // If is_fixed = true, then variable is a parameter
    double value;      // Numerical value
    std::string name;  // Description of variable (to identify it by name)
};

struct NODE{
public: 
    VAR_TYPE X, Y, Z;  
    /* VAR_TYPE is a structure of primitive types */
};

class States{
private:
    std::vector <NODE_ptr> node;                  // shared ptr to struct NODE
    std::vector <PROP_DICTIONARY_ptr> property;   // CAN NOT be part of Parameter
    std::vector <ELEMENT_ptr> element;            // CAN NOT be part of Parameter

public:
    /* ect */
    void set_X_reference ( Parameter &T , int i ) { T.push_var( &node[i]->X ); }
    void set_Y_reference ( Parameter &T , int i ) { T.push_var( &node[i]->Y ); }    
    void set_Z_reference ( Parameter &T , int i ) { T.push_var( &node[i]->Z ); }

    bool get_node_bool_X( int i ) { return node[i]->X.is_fixed; }
    // repeat for Y and Z
};

class Parameter{
private:
    std::vector <VAR_TYPE*> var;
public:
    /* ect */
};

int main(){
    States S;
    Parameter P;

    /* Here I initialize and set S, and do other stuff */

    // Now I assign components in States to Parameters
    for(int n=0 ; n<S.size_of_nodes() ; n++ ){
        if ( S.get_node_bool_X(n)==true ){
            S.set_X_reference ( P , n );
        };
        // repeat if statement for Y and Z
    };

    /* Now P points selected to data in S, and I can
     * modify the contents of S through P
     */

    return 0;
};
```

### Update

The reason this issue cropped up is I am working with Fortran legacy code. To sum up this Fotran code - it's a numerical simulation of a flight vehicle. This code has a fairly rigid procedural framework one must work within, which comes with a pre-defined list of allowable Fortran types. The Fortran glue code can create an instance of a C++ object (in actuality, a reference from the perspective of Fortran), but is not aware what is contained in it (other means are used to extract C++ data into Fortran).

The problem that I encountered is when a C++ module is dynamically linked to the Fortran glue code, C++ objects have to be initialized each instance the C++ code is called. This happens by virtue of how the Fortran template is defined.

To avoid this cycle of re-initializing objects, I plan to use 'State' as a container class. The Fortran code allows a 'State' object, which has an arbitrary definition; but I plan to use it to harness all relevant information about the model. The idea is to use the Parameters class (which is exposed and updated by the Fortran code) to update variables in States.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the Parameter class a pointer to the entire State object? Then just make everything that shouldn't be changed private.

Comment: I'm only showing limited attributes in the State class, but State is populated with others types. Only some attributes in States can be Parameters. It's my fault for not being more specific in the question, but I can't copy the entire object (or reference it).

Comment: Posting some more code would be helpful.

Comment: If you posted more information about your intended usage, we could probably be of more help.

Comment: Yes, I agree. In hind sight, I was a bit vague with the question. Hopefully my update will shed more light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is legal C++ (although some parts of the code are missing, so I have to guess what they do) -- you *can* take pointers and references to member variables like this. But the question whether this is moral (or "sound") depends heavily on the situation.

It seems to me that you are trying to hide the semantics of which data member (`x`, etc) a particular object belongs to with your `Parameter` type. So, when actually accessing the contents of your `VAR_TYPE*` collection, you will not have that information.

That could be desired or it could be code smell. I'm leaning towards the latter. If `x`, `y` and `z` can serve similar roles, it might be better to replace them by *one* [`std::array<VAR_TYPE,3>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and access them by index rather than going to the trouble of creating this wrapper type that serves the only purpose to add exactly this indirect access functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I posted a few more lines in the original question. This code will eventually be merged with Fortran legacy code, and In doing so, I am forced to adopted the Fortran framework. The explanation as to why I have Parameters point to data in States comes down to this: if I stuck to the Fortran framework, I would have to re-initialize data structures each time the C++ portion is called. Instead, what I prefer to do is update variables (bypassing numerous initializations). Parameters is exposed to Fortran; States is not.